# Mail.app send mail hook

Tags: mac, email, plugins, apple-mail

Is there any way to run a script whenever the user tries to send mail?  I'm particularly interested in ensuring that outbound mail doesn't have a blank subject line.

Solutions that involve plug-ins are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's no easy way to do this via AppleScript, however there's a plugin that warns in case of blank subject, it's [Subjectivity](http://www.joeyhagedorn.com/projects/subjectivity). It works only with Tiger, since Leopard and Snow Leopard's Mail.app warns you if you leave subject blank.

I found [this blog post](http://eaganj.free.fr/weblog/?post/2009/07/14/Demystifying-Mail.app-Plugins-on-Leopard) on writing Mail plugins, however I didn't try to write one.

Comment: It works.  And the source is nice, easy to read Python code, which I think I can use for other kinds of scripting.